# Interesting Base summation contest math problem

Tags: summation, contest-math, number-systems

The problem is as follows:

Let $N_b=1_b+2_b+\cdots+100_b$ where $b$ is an integer greater than $2$. Compute the number of values of $b$ for which the sum of the squares of the digits of $N_b$ is at most $512$.

I originally tried to find the maximum case for which this held true, by going until it no longer worked, but I realized that being less than or equal to $512$ was an intermittent pattern that might not be easy to tell when it stopped. We were given $20$ minutes, no calculators. If I remember correctly, I think the answer happened to be $30$. Can anyone tell me why it is this and how to prove it quickly?

Comment: I don't quite understand the pattern.  I assume you mean $1, 2, 3, 4, \cdots, 100$ (i.e. base $10$ numbers).  I also assume that $x_b$ means the value of the digit string $x$ in base $b$...but then the base must be _at least_ base $10$ (not at least base $2$--and it cannot actually be base $2$).

Comment: If instead this is the sum of the first "$100$" numbers (notice the quotes), then the sum can be written down (although I don't know if that helps or not): $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ in base $10$ when $n$ is the $100^\text{th}$ value, which would be $b^2$, given, in base $10$, the sum is $\frac{b^2\left(b^2 + 1\right)}{2}$.

Comment: @Jared: It does help. The base-$b$ representation of $\frac{b^2\left(b^2 + 1\right)}{2}$ is not hard to determine, if odd and even $b$ are considered separately. See my answer below.

Comment: This is purely commentary but note that we are talking about bases yet the number $512$ is given _no base_!  The assumption seems to be that $512$ is base $10$ (and I think this is correct)...but there is no suggestion that this is the case.  If our "$512$" is of a different base (not base $10$, e.g. it's base $6$) then I would imagine that our answer would change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $$N_b= 101_b\left(\frac{100_b}{2}\right)=\frac{b^4+b^2}{2}=b^2\left(\dfrac{b^2+1}{2}\right).$$

If $b$ is odd, 
$$b^2\left(\frac{b^2+1}{2}\right)=b^2\left(\frac{b-1}{2}b+\frac{b+1}{2}\right)=\frac{b-1}{2}b^3+\frac{b+1}{2}b^2+0b+0,$$
so $N_b = \left(d_3d_2d_1d_0\right)_b$ where $d_3=\dfrac{b-1}{2}d_2=\dfrac{b+1}{2}$ and $d_1=d_0=0$, and the sum of the squares of the digits of $N_b$ is $(\dfrac{b-1}{2})^2+(\dfrac{b+1}{2})^2$.

If $b$ is even, 
$$b^2\left(\frac{b^2+1}{2}\right)=(b^2+1)\left(\frac{b^2}{2}\right)=\frac{b}{2}b^3+0b^2+\frac{b}{2}b+0,$$
so $N_b = \left(d_3d_2d_1d_0\right)_b$ where $d_3=\dfrac{b}{2},d_2=0,d_1=\dfrac{b}{2},$ and $d_0=0$, and the sum of the squares of the digits of $N_b$ is $2(\dfrac{b}{2})^2$.

It’s not hard to see that $N_b$ is an increasing sequence in $b$, and that the sum of the digits in $N_{32}=(g0g0)_{32}$ is 512.

Comment: *I originally said the answer was 30, but I’d jumped the gun since that’s what John thought the answer was. The correct answer seems to be 32.*

Comment: But 1 and 2 are excluded, because it has to be greater than 2, so I think it is still 30

Comment: Thanks for the correction. So the $b$-values for which the requirement holds are the 20 integers $b$ for which $3\le b \le 30$.